# Core Data - Understanding multiple relationships

Tags: ios, core-data

I started learning core data.
After working with some basic tutorials with 1 relationship (for example 1 teacher - 20 students) I want to try something "bigger".

I want to create a tournament app. This is how my model looks like right now:

[image: Model]

So with the app you can create player profiles, exhibition games and tournaments. The user can check the "matchups" between two players. For example player "max" played against player "tony" 25 exhibition games and 8 games in tournaments.

In a SQL-database, I would create three tables (Same like in the picture above). But the table match would have another attribute "tournamentID" and the playerIDs.
So with the tournamentID I could still check if it's an tournament game or an exhibition game.

But how about core data? Which relations do I have to create so that I can distinguish between a exhibition game and a tournament game?

Comment: What **is** the difference between an exhibition game and a tournament game?

Comment: There is no difference. The only difference is that a tournament game is linked to a specific tournament. The normal exhibition game is just a game without a link to a tournament.

Answer (score 1):

the model you have there will only work for two players, so you should move the match details - players and goals scored into a linking table.
How about this?
[image]

Comment: Add the inverse relationships; always.

Comment: @Mike For every match, there will be many MatchEntries, one for each player

Comment: Ahhh ok I got you! But how Would look an request when i want to get all the games where player x played against player y?

Comment: D'oh - only two players per match! I don't know why I was thinking of football.  In that case case we should simplify the model

Comment: I don't have access to XCode right now, but you could remove the MatchDetails object, add player1ID, player2ID, player1Goals and player2Goals to the Match entity.

Answer (score 1):

We can simplify the data model further if you can use the player name as the ID, so that 'mike' and 'tony' are stored in Match.

in that case it becomes a simple case of using a search predicate to match player 1 and player 2

there a few good tutorials out there, including www.jamesonquave.com/core-data-in-swift-tutorial-part-2

Comment: Do I have to set custom IDs? I thought core data does it automatically.

Comment: what about custom classes for the objects? What's your opinion? Should I create custom classes or should I get everything with `let playerName = managedObject.valueForKey("name")` ?

Comment: I load everything into classes matching my entities

Comment: So you create classes that are equal to your entities?

Comment: I do., then I can load data directly from the database into the entities.  If there are any other attributes that are derived and not stored, I populate them at the same time.

Comment: Can you give me a Code example? That Sounds interesting.